# Create crystal report with crostab object through code file

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crosstab

Am new to crystal report and this stackoverflow. with the lot of hope am writing this to get help. It will be encouraging if you provide support.

I want to convert  Power builder library(.pbl) files to  crystal report files(.rpt) .

In that process, i need to integrate all the objects available/supported in crystal report .
Now am in the process of converting Crosstab objects.

So, How can i provide the necessary bound values (like rows,colums,summary) for crosstabobject to form crosstab in crystal report.

For this i need to mention all the specifications in my code(.cs) file . i need the code for "Crosstabobject" implementaion.

If anyone could help on this, I will be very thankful to you

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The RAS (report-application server) SDK offer the most functionality when it comes to modifying a RPT--much more than the Crystal Reports SDK.  The in-process version of the SDK no supports doing the modification on the client.

It appears, however, that the SDK doesn't offer the functionality to create/modify a cross-tab object, only to delete it.  Supporting documentation from the [Java-edition of the RAS SDK](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/bip/40/ras/en/index.html?com/crystaldecisions/sdk/occa/report/definition/CrossTabObject.html).

** edit **
This appears to be the case in the .Net SDK as well.  Here's a link to the [Report Application Server .NET SDK](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/xi4_rassdk_net_api_en.zip) in CHM format.